# Get list of sql query with error with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

On *ORACLE* database there are triggers that can be fired when an error occurs on `SCHEMA`.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOG_SCHEMA_ERRORS_IN_TABLE AFTER SERVERERROR ON SCHEMA.
```

So one can populate a table with.

I am looking for a way to do that on PostgreSQL.

Comment: No way to do that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is there a way to populate a table with errors when an error occurs ?
As a last resort, by inserting the log file into this table.
 - With a batch
- With a postgresql extention

Comment: You might be able to write a C extension for that, but I think it will be almost impossible to insert something into a table when a transaction is being aborted.